# Something Wrong With My Asynchronous JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fs

```
class Main {
    constructor() {
        this.argument = process.argv.splice(2);
        this.fileToCopy = this.argument[0];
        this.destination = this.argument[1] ? this.argument[1] : '';

        this.callAdress = process.cwd();
        this.finalAdress = `${this.callAdress}\\` + this.destination;
       

        //Problematic Part
        if(this.fileExists(this.fileToCopy, this.finalAdress)) console.log("EXISTS")
        else console.log("DOESNT EXISTS");
    }

    async fileExists(file, path) {
        try {
            let files = await fs.readdir(path);
            
            return files.includes(file);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("ERROR", e)
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

im trying to check if file exists in directroy, using promises for fs,the problematic part always returns true. im out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and step line by line through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `if (this.fileExists...)` which is equivalent to `if (true)` because `this.fileExists` always return a Promise, which would be implicitly coerced to boolean value of `true`

So you should call `fileExists` with `await` instead, and wrap this call in an IIFE function

And remember to put a semicolon at the beginning of IIFE function to avoid concatnating with the previous line (`this.destination(async...)`)

```
class Main {
  constructor() {
    this.argument = process.argv.splice(2)
    this.fileToCopy = this.argument[0]
    this.destination = this.argument[1] ? this.argument[1] : ''

    this.callAdress = process.cwd()
    this.finalAdress = `${this.callAdress}\\` + this.destination

    ;(async () => {
      if (await this.fileExists(this.fileToCopy, this.finalAdress))
        console.log('EXISTS')
      else console.log('DOESNT EXISTS')
    })()
  }

  async fileExists(file, path) {
    try {
      let files = await fs.readdir(path)

      return files.includes(file)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR', e)
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @hgb123 Why you need to wrap this call in an IIFE function ?

Comment: @Sohan because `this.fileExists` is called with `await`, and AFIK, we could not make constructor `async`..